# How to install Scribe Java Lib in eclipse

Tags: java, scribe

I am trying to install the Scribe Java Lib in eclipse but unable to succeed. I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in the documentation but no luck. I am new to Maven. Kindly help me figure it out.

This is the scribe documentation

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.objecteffects</groupId>
<artifactId>template</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>template</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- version numbers that are repeated in the same pom. -->
    <version.slf4j>1.7.6</version.slf4j>
    <version.hibernate>4.3.5.Final</version.hibernate>
    <version.guice-persist>3.0</version.guice-persist>
    <version.postgresql>9.1-901.jdbc4</version.postgresql>
    <version.hsqldb>2.3.2</version.hsqldb>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>3.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>scribe-java-mvn-repo</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/</url>

        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>

            <version>1.0.13</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>

            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>

            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>

            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>

            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>

            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-persist</artifactId>

            <version>${version.guice-persist}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guiceberry</groupId>
            <artifactId>guiceberry</artifactId>

            <version>3.3.1</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>

            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>

            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>

        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>

            <version>${version.hsqldb}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>

            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

            <version>4.11</version>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is a slightly edited version of my parent pom for a multi-module project; hopefully I didn't screw up anything when I edited it.